# Where to declare BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT for serialization

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost

I want to serialize my data and i have polymorphic classes .

Initially when i was learning the process of the Serialization i declared the Inherited class in their header files.

```
  Header file for Sphere which is sub class of geometry
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Sphere)
```

but when i tried doing in my project i got the linker error2005 stating that the object is already defined in the object.

So i tried declaring the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Sphere) in the cpp file but than i got error message derived class not registered or exported.

Eventually i got it working by declaring the derived class in the Main file.

```
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Sphere, "Sphere");
```

But the problem here is that if i have 30 objects i will need to declare them in the main file and if i add any new classes than again i need to declare them in main file.

Can i define the export in their header or  cpp files of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to separate the export KEY and IMPLEMENTATION.

I have some very complete answers up, some of which also touch on polymorphism and abstract bases. See there for good suggestions:

- The simplest introduction [Boost Serialization - Exporting in multiple CPP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442778/boost-serialization-exporting-in-multiple-cpp-files/32447142#32447142) (no code, but perhaps most explanatory)
- A complete example with more explanation and documentation quotes, in multiple translation units: [Boost serialization, loading an archived class by base type gives wrong data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389674/boost-serialization-loading-an-archived-class-by-base-type-gives-wrong-data/51411997#51411997)
- [BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_* macros are not working like register_type()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545233/boost-class-export-macros-are-not-working-like-register-type/52546594#52546594) (complete with several source files and makefile)
- Another sample with multiple translation units [boost serialization of nested struct does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089485/boost-serialization-of-nested-struct-does-not-work/23092534#23092534)
- A subtle pitfall mixing static polymorphism and dynamic polymorphism: [Serialize Polymorph Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567384/serialize-polymorph-interface/52572719#52572719)
- [Why does boost::serialize not work despite everything seeming right? ("unregistered class")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970956/why-does-boostserialize-not-work-despite-everything-seeming-right-unregiste/30974971#30974971)
- Rocket science hacks: [Boost serialization of derived class with private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893929/boost-serialization-of-derived-class-with-private-members/45977995#45977995)